# Redirect sub domain to main domain without effecting sub folders with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, multisite

My situation is as follows:

- I've have a new website at my main domain. Example: mywebsite.com.
- My old portfolio is located at an old sub domain: portfolio.mywebsite.com.
- All portfolio items can be found in a sub directory at the portfolio site.
- So portfolio item 1 can be found at portfolio.mywebsite.com/item-1, etc.
- The sub domain is running WordPress with Multisite enabled.
- The sub domain and main domain are hosted by different web hosts.

I want to redirect all traffic from portfolio.mywebsite.com to mywebsite.com/portfolio. But I don't want to redirect traffic from the portfolio items, since I don't have time to build a new portfolio yet. Therefor I also need to be able to acces the wp-admin folder on the sub domain.

In short: How do I redirect traffic from portfolio.mywebsite.com to mywebsite.com/portfolio without effecting all the other urls? :)

Best regards,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand well your problem i think that you can use a simple plugin for redirection like [Safe Redirect Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/)

It's very simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing this redirect rule in root of `portfolio.mywebsite.com` as **very first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ http://mywebsite.com/portfolio [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! But now it redirects everything except portfolio.mywebsite.com/. So that's exactly the opposite what I'm trying to accomplish! :P

Comment: Where is this htaccess located and what URL you entered in browser?