# Redirecting subdomain to main domain keeping access to url within main domain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have initially a wordpress mu blog in maindomain.com/subdomain

I want to keep that but be able to redirect subdomain.maindomain.com/article1 to maindomain.com/subdomain/article1

I first tried to create a subdomain using my hosting cpanel and do a redirect from subdomain.maindomain.com to maindomain.com/subdomain. To my surprise it doesn't work with article1

So I rollbacked and searched for another solution. I found this [Redirect sub domain to main domain without effecting sub folders with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915825/redirect-sub-domain-to-main-domain-without-effecting-sub-folders-with-htaccess) but I'm not sure to understand wildcard * and fear to not be able to access my blog anymore so I'd like to have confirmation:

Should I do something like this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have an access to your htaccess file, maybe you could try to add a RewriteRule (with the QSA (QueryString Append) flag only if you want to preserve other parameters, like /article1?x=y)   :

So, in the htaccess of your subdomain.example.com :

RewriteRule ^(.*)? http://example.com/subdomain/$1 [QSA]